# Error creating BucketPolicy in CloudFormation yaml

Tags: amazon-s3, yaml, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to use the following yaml to create an S3 Bucket Policy in CloudFormation:

```
  cloudTrailBucketPolicy:
    Type:  "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy"
    Properties:
      Bucket:
        Ref: cloudtrailBucket
      PolicyDocument:
        -
          Action:
            - "s3:GetBucketAcl"
          Effect:  Allow
          Resource:
            Fn::Join:
              - ""
              -
                - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                -
                  Ref: cloudtrailBucket
                - "/*"
          Principal:  "*"
        -
          Action:
            - "s3:PutObject"
          Effect:  Allow
          Resource:
            Fn::Join:
              - ""
              -
                - "arn:aws:s3:::"
                -
                  Ref: cloudtrailBucket
                - "/*"
          Principal:
            Service:  cloudtrail.amazonaws.com
```

When I try to do this, I get a message that "Value of property PolicyDocument must be an object"

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

Looks like you solved the issue, but for readability you can compress your formatting by using !Sub and knowing that action allows single values as well as list. One of the main reasons I like yaml is that you use less vertical.

`PolicyDocument:
  -
    Action: "s3:GetBucketAcl"
    Effect:  Allow
    Resource: !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${cloudtrailBucket}
    Principal:  "*"
  -
    Action: "s3:PutObject"
    Effect:  Allow
    Resource: !Sub arn:aws:s3:::${cloudtrailBucket}/*
    Principal:
      Service: cloudtrail.amazonaws.com`

Answer (score 3):

The [`PolicyDocument`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-policy.html#cfn-s3-bucketpolicy-policydocument) property of the [`AWS::S3::BucketPolicy`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-policy.html) Resource has a required type of JSON Object. The YAML template in your question incorrectly provides a JSON Array containing two JSON Objects as the value of the `PolicyDocument` property, hence the error message you received.

To fix this error, the objects should be properly nested within a [`Statement`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html#Statement) element which is missing from the current template.

Refer to the [IAM Policy Elements Reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_elements.html) for more detail on IAM Policy Document syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Ahhh.  s3:GetBucketAcl is an action on a bucket.  I removed the /* in the first statement and it worked.  Gee.  Super helpful error message.